# Erwin API question adding relationships to model

Tags: relationship, erwin

Has anyone got example code to add relationships to Erwin model using Erwin API. E.g. adding a new key_group.
Adding entities and attributes is pretty straightforward, struggling with figuring out how to add relationships.

I have written code to read key group properties and check if relationship exists, unsure about adding key groups and properties.